# Why does this algorithm guarantee 60 updates per second?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

```
run() {
    lastTime = currentTime();
    timer = currentTime();
    ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;

    delta = 0;
    frames = 0;
    updates = 0;

    while (true) {
        now = currentTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        frames++;

        if (currentTime() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            print("FPS: " + frames + " UPS: " + updates);
            frames = updates = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the maths behind this algorithm. For some reason, it correctly outputs "UPS : 60"  (updates per second) constantly.

Could someone explain it?

E: currentTime() just returns the current system time (measured from the moment the program is executed). If it helps, assume that the $i^\text{th}$ instruction takes $\delta_i>0$ seconds to execute.

E2: Still waiting for the reopening...

Comment: The behavior of a program is not entirely a mathematical issue, and hence you need to present the specific mathematical problem you want help with to be on-topic here.  For example, your code relies on calls to `currentTime()` and `tick()` that are not expressed/implemented in the code shown.  Note also the requirements of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you wish to ask for debugging help at StackOverflow.

Comment: @hardmath I believe I've made it on-topic now. `currentTime` just returns the system time, counting from when the program was open, and I removed `tick()` because it didn't do anything towards the functioning of the algorithm.

Comment: Dividing by 'ns` converts the time passed from nanoseconds to frames. Hence `delta` keeps accumulating the updates that *should* have been made at 60 fps, and then the inner `while` loops turns these should-have-made updates into actual updates. It follows that UPS is always very close to 60 (the denominator in the definition of  `ns`), possibly 59 or 61 on very rare occasions. Such exceptions may occur more often, though, if the loop (or update) execution time becomes significant; and also if the loop is executed very fast and the precision of the type of var `delta` starts to play a role

Comment: I still don't understand what keeps the updates at $60$, or for what it's worth why they could be $59,61$, could you elaborate a bit? All these numbers should be stored in double precision floating point.